# Clean way to manage parse-dictionaries that contain function names

Tags: python, dictionary

Well to directly explain it, I wish to "parse" user input. - Simple input string -> output string.

However there isn't any "logical" way to parse this apart from simply checking the input string against a dictionary (regex check). Now this isn't difficult at all - I'd just create a dictionary with regex search string keys & regex/function pointer values.

However the problem is: there will be around ~100-200 "keys" probably. And I can easily see myself wishing to add/remove keys (maybe merge) in the future.
So is there a way that creating such a dictionary looks "structured"? Keeping the "data" away from the "code". (Data would be the regex-functionname pairs)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you trying to not have a giant dictionary full of string literals in your code? If that's the case, my first idea would be to store the dictionary in the JSON format in a file and read in the file upon program execution.

Comment: If the user input has any formatting at all maybe take a look at the pyparsing library. Other than that I would agree to save it as JSON and read it to a variable on execution.

Comment: @paul23: It would also help to see a small sample of the dictionary.

Comment: @timgeb: well it's a library with string : functionpointer. key-value pairs. Also this question is quite language agnostic - I'm not sure if the code will be written in python (though I think it is as it's basically a large parsing of user data) or something else.

Comment: @paul23 still looks like a job for JSON to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the dictionary in the JSON format in  file, with the function names as ordinary strings. Demo how to load a JSON file:

Content of sample file:

```
{"somestring":"myfunction"}
```

Code:

```
import json
d = json.load(open('very_small_dic.txt', 'r'))
print(d) # {'somestring': 'myfunction'}
```

How to get the string:function mapping:

First you load the dictionary from a file as illustrated in the code above. After that, you build a new dictionary where the strings of the function names are replaced by the actual functions. Demo:

```
def myfunction(x):
    return 2*x

d = {'somestring': 'myfunction'} # in the real code this came from json.load
d = {k:globals()[v] for k,v in d.items()}
print(d) # {'somestring': <function myfunction at 0x7f36e69d8c20>}
print(d['somestring'](42)) # 84
```

You could also store your functions in a separate file `myfunctions.py` and use `getattr`. This is probably a cleaner way than using `globals`.

```
import myfunctions # for this demo, this module only contains the function myfunction

d = {'somestring': 'myfunction'} # in the real code this came from json.load
d = {k:getattr(myfunctions,v) for k,v in d.items()}
print(d) # {'somestring': <function myfunction at 0x7f36e69d8c20>}
print(d['somestring'](42)) # 84
```

Comment: The problem here is that the "keys" should be pointers/ids for functions. I need to match a string to a function.

Comment: "string":function.. I like the second method as it really also separates the "user functions" from the "core program" - creating the correct layers of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use JsonSchema (http://json-schema.org/example1.html).

I think in order to transform values belonging to certain keys you'd certainly have to write a function to perform the conversions.

If you'd just like to sanitize the input based on the presence of certain keys - It would be ideal to convert it into a dictionary, define a schema and then check for the (required/optional fields)/the type or validate a field against a list of enums.